# how to create javascript effect automatically shut elament?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sdk

...
I want to ask about use of effects, so I have a few buttons and each button if pressed will display the HTML element `<div>` and I've made the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#label').click(function(){
        $('#menu1').toggle("speed");
    });

    $('#label2').click(function(){
        $('#menu2').fadeToggle("speed");
    });

    $('#label3').click(function(){
        $('#menu3').slideToggle("speed");
    });
});
```

[image]

I would like if one of the menu is clicked element  from another menu closed.
I ask for guidance and what's the solution?

Comment: FYI: Code is always better than an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the items a common class and call

```
$('.menu-item:visible').hide();
```

**Basic example:**

```js
$(".tabs").on("click", "a", function () {
  
  var anchor = $(this),
      id = anchor.attr("href"),
      menuToToggle = $(id);
  
  anchor.closest("li").toggleClass("active", !menuToToggle.is(":visible")).siblings(".active").removeClass("active");
  
  $(".menu-item:visible").not(menuToToggle).hide();
  menuToToggle.fadeToggle();
  
  
  
});
```

```css
.menu-item { display: none; }
li.active{ background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs">
  <li><a href="#menu1">One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#menu2">Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#menu3">Three</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="menu1" class="menu-item">Menu 1 item</div>
<div id="menu2" class="menu-item">Menu 2 item</div>
<div id="menu3" class="menu-item">Menu 3 item</div>
```

Comment: from sample code that you provide can not walk? I use IGNSDK

Comment: I have no clue what IGNSDK is and the code can work if you adjust it to your needs. It is a basic example. You need to adjust it based on what your html is.

Comment: IGNSDK is development tool,

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.menu-link').click(function() {

  $('[id^=menu]').not('#menu' + this.id).slideUp();
  $('#menu' + this.id).slideToggle();

});
```

```css
.menu-item {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><a href="#" id="1" class="menu-link">Menu 1</a>  <a href="#" id="2" class="menu-link">Menu 2</a>  <a href="#" id="3" class="menu-link">Menu 3</a>
<div id="menu1" class="menu-item">Menu 1</div>
<div id="menu2" class="menu-item">Menu 2</div>
<div id="menu3" class="menu-item">Menu 3</div>
```

Comment: with this example I will try to develop it

Comment: from sample code that you provide can not walk? I use IGNSDK